# Cancel/Allow react-router transition after confirmation in via dialog box on ComponentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm building a Redux application. I want user to confirmation if they want to leave the Component without saving the data or cancel the transition and save it and maybe then leave.

For example, is there any way to stop a component from unmounting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better way is to create the following `routerWillLeave` hook if you are already using `react-router`.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, this.beforeUnload);
}

routerWillLeave(e) {
  // check for a condition here
  if (this.state.allowLeave === false) {
    const message = 'Are you sure?';
    (e || window.event).returnValue = message;
    return message;
  }
}
```

Also, to make sure `this.props.router` is available, you must export your component as:

```
export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

See docs at https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md.

Comment: Thank for Help! I'm trying above-mentioned method and it's throwing following error, 

createTransitionManager.js?aa7a:133 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '\_\_id\_\_' of undefined

Comment: @RamanChoudhary That looks like a problem in your code. I haven't introduced `id` anywhere

Comment: this error is coming from createTransitionManager.js,  Cannot read property '\_\_id\_\_' of undefined. BTW, I forget to mention, this is not directly connected with <Router>

`<Route path="/microtask/:microtaskId" name="microtaskId" component={Page}/>`

It's a direct child of Page component.

Comment: If you are accessing `this.props.router` inside the `Page` component, then make sure when you export Page component, you wrap it with `withRouter ` higher order component. Also I think you should be using the latest version of all the packages, React, React-DOM & React-Router.

Comment: The documentation link is  no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent component from unmounting. You can use `window.onbeforeunload` to prevent user from closing current tab and save data in background on `componentWillUnmount`. That's how I do it in my app.

If `window.onbeforeunload` returns anything except `undefined` it will trigger a confirmation popup.

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => 'Are you sure?';
```